# I am using custom build sidebar component and not sure how to add data

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuex, sidebar

I have managed to install this [SideBar](https://medium.com/@rmmmsy/creating-an-animated-sidebar-component-with-vue-and-vuex-9f7c6aa19fce) into my Vuex/Laravel project but as it's shows in the example the guy used

```
<div :class="$style.sidebar"/>
```

When I try to change this to

```
<div :class="$style.sidebar">Content</div>
```

it doesn't work and when I change this to

```
<template>
<div :class="$style.sidebar"/>
<div>Content</div>
</template>
```

It obviously give me error as I learned so far that all content should be inside one tag.

I want to use the sidebar to display my cart with data displayed in a table and it should be reactive too.

Here is my cart which I want to move inside the sidebar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was doing something else was generating error. I sorted the issue and tried again with following codes

```
<template>

<div :class="$style.sidebar">
  <cartbarmobile></cartbarmobile>
</div>

</template>
```

and it worked just fine :)